# How do data structures like graphs, trees etc. derive their time complexities and behaviour even though they are implemented using lists/arrays?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, graph, tree, time-complexity

Doesn't the behavior and properties of these data structures affect the behavior of "higher" data structures like graphs, binary trees, linked lists etc. ?
for example : the access of an array is `O(1)` so how does this property affect or factor-in in the time complexity of say binary tree `O (log n)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(1)` is the time-complexity of accessing an array element by its index.

You can use an array as the backing store for a binary tree. This will indeed give you `O(1)` time-complexity *for the operations that end up doing an array access by index*, but not for other things.

For example, you can get the root element of the tree in `O(1)` -- this is just retrieving it from the array at position 0.

But if you want to find out if an element exists in the tree, this comes down to (a special form of) binary search, i.e. `O(log n)`

Also note that not every operation on an array is `O(1)`. A binary search is `O(log n)`, and that assumes that the array is sorted. If it is not, you need to do linear search, i.e. `O(n)`.